# Setting a sprite's size with pixels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am relatively new to C#, but I know my way around most of the basics. I know this question has been asked many times, and, after nearly 2 hours of searching I still can't seem to find an answer that works, so please bear with me.

I'm creating a 2D Unity game for iOS, and I need to be able to get the size of the screen, *(I know how to do this, it is Screen.width / Screen.height)* and with that, set the size of a sprite. I'm trying to get 7 sprites (width-wise) on the screen, but I need it to adjust with the device. Hard coding numbers won't do here. So, to achieve this, I need a way to scale by pixels, which I'm not sure how to do, or if it is even possible with Unity. If there is any other way, please let me know.

*(Yes, I have tried using Rect and RectTransform, it either doesn't do what I need, or I'm using it wrong. could be either.)*

Comment: You're probably using RectTransform incorrectly. The Canvas should be set to have anchors of (0,0), (1,1). The spirits are then in a horizontal layout group that has anchors of (0,0),(1,1) and resizes children to fit inside it. I think. Not able to check right now and I always feel like I'm fighting layout groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to use a combination of math functions that determined the width of the screen, they I had to perfect some of the numbers from there.

Here is a general idea of what works:

```
//Declaration Of Variables
float blockSize = Screen.width / 8.75f;
float blockDistanceX = Screen.width / 8.75f;
void Start()
{
    //Extra variables that couldn't be declared earlier
    float xValue = blockDistanceX * -1f * 3.8f;
    float layerPos = -1500;

    //Creates new Block
    GameObject block = Instantiate(objectPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Quaternion.identity, parent: canvas);
    block.transform.localScale = new Vector2(blockSize, blockSize);
    block.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(xValue, layerPos);
}
```